# Encrypting database credentials

Tags: mysql, database, encryption, credentials

Firstly to explain, we have some websites which all connect to a central database. As a rule we don't give clients access to the FTP for their website so they cant access any files with the DB credentials in them. 99.9% of the time this is fine.

However we are having a client insisting they have full FTP access. They want to add advertising / tracking stuff in, and I have set them up their own database and a locked down FTP in another directory, but thats not good enough apparently.

Now I am sure they don't intend to steal our mysql credentials and connect and wipe out our DB's but no doubt you will agree its a huge security risk.

Is there any way to:

a) connect to the database without them seeing the credentials within the code

b) stopping them from adding their own code and connecting to the central database, only their own

Pretty sure nothing is going to be 100% secure, as giving them FTP access means they can do the same as I can, but wondering if anyone else has any ideas?

Comment: yeah, charge them a bit extra, say 1000 a year, or more, and let them blow up their own box

Comment: Before talking about encryption, I would suggest you to use a specific user to connect to your database from your script. This user should have limited rights (select of course, insert and update also, and probably not much more than that). And when you speak about a central database, do you mean someone having access to the database could access other users data ?

Comment: The simple answer is that you need an intermediary between the code to which they have access and the processes to which you want to deny access.  This intermediary can then perform whatever checks you deem appropriate, be they verifying the codebase with which it is interacting or simply limiting the operations that can be performed.  If the latter, you have merely created an API through which all database activity is performed; on simple applications, I have created such an API within the database itself using MySQL account credentials and stored procedures.

Comment: @Bartdude yes, hence why we dont allow people access

Comment: @eggyal yeah have considered creating an API for this, but at considerable cost of time in creating a restful api and then converting existing code to work with the api its not really an option just yet. as i said, 99.9% of the time its not an issue

Comment: Well, I would say the biggest security problem is that then, and eggyal's remark seems pretty much to be the answer.... I don't see any easy way to obfuscate credentials in the code

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this "securely" without writing a RESTful API (which you've indicated is not feasible), is to create for them a special user account in your MySQL, that cannot access records not owned by them.  Truthfully you should do this for all your clients if you're doing it "right," although I understand that can be a lot of maintenance.

Regarding encryption, there isn't a way to encrypt your DB credentials for the client and have them decrypted for the DB login without some intermediary code.  This shouldn't matter though if the client has their own MySQL account for access.

Answer (score 0):

For people that still are looking for some solutions I found a nice tutorial on how to make credentials more safe. The author proposes to create additional layer encrypting password and decrypting within app.

https://maciejzalwert.medium.com/quick-tip-for-developers-to-protect-against-credentials-leak-b203a4d80b3b